# compiler error use custom shader on a geometry

Tags: ios, scenekit

I want to do some custom work in custom shader, but get a internal error when run it. compile seems ok, but run will get the error message:

error building shaders : Error Domain=AGXMetalG4P Code=1 "Compiler encountered an internal error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Compiler encountered an internal error}
[SCNKit ERROR] display link thread seems stuck

```
SCNProgram *program = [[SCNProgram alloc] init];

program.fragmentFunctionName = @"myVertex";
program.vertexFunctionName = @"myFragment";

mySceneNode.geometry.program = program
```

and the shader:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;
#include <SceneKit/scn_metal>

struct MyNodeBuffer {
float4x4 modelTransform;
float4x4 modelViewTransform;
float4x4 normalTransform;
float4x4 modelViewProjectionTransform;
};

typedef struct {
     float3 position [[ attribute(SCNVertexSemanticPosition) ]];
} MyVertexInput;

struct SimpleVertex
{
     float4 position [[position]];
};


vertex SimpleVertex myVertex(MyVertexInput in [[ stage_in ]],
                           constant SCNSceneBuffer& scn_frame [[buffer(0)]],
                         constant MyNodeBuffer& scn_node [[buffer(1)]])

{
    SimpleVertex vert;
   vert.position = scn_node.modelViewProjectionTransform *     float4(in.position, 1.0);

   vert.position = float4(in.position,0);

   return vert;
}

fragment half4 myFragment(SimpleVertex in [[stage_in]])
{
    half4 color;
    color = half4(0.0 ,1.0 ,0.0, 1.0);

    return color;
 }
```

Comment: which versions of Xcode and iOS do you test this with?

Comment: I am testing on IOS 9.3.2 and Xcode 7.3,1 @mnuages

Comment: Did you try `#include "scn_metal"` instead of `#include <SceneKit/scn_metal>` ?